# Container - Id is shown as 2000

Tags: linux, container, oracle

I installed Oracle Container using the image: oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g:latest - on a Linux machine.
While doing, I copied one .sql file into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d using "volumes" as shown below:

```
volumes:
    - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

After the container was created, when logged into container, the Owner for the folder "docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" is shown as "2000".
When verified for user with the ID, nothing is shown.

[image: User ID shown as 2000]

Any suggestion about who is the user with ID as 2000?
And what is the reason for this - Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you use `volumes` you are mounting a host directory/file into a container.  The permissions would be the UID/GID that own that location (`./sql`) on the host.

Comment: @GracefulRestart - Thanks, this answered my question. But, I did not see any option to make this as "answer" (tick-mark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `volumes` mounts a location from the host within a container.

This means the permissions would be relative to the host the container is running on.

If you check the `./sql` location on the host, and the host's user list, you will probably be able to discover a user with ID 2000